# Need to redirect to where user came from on session timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

A user has 2 ways of getting to this MVC3 website.

1. Through a log in screen.
2. Redirect from a different website.

I'm currently just showing a session time out page if the session timed out.  However, the business now wants to redirect the user back to where he came from on session timeout.

How would I know where the user came from?

By the time I'm out of session, I don't even know who the user was.  Although, that wouldn't make a difference, since the same user could come from either place.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. You could use a similar technique to what happens when you request a page that requires authentication. In that case, you are redirected to the login action, but the original request is added to the query string with `http://localhost/Account/Login?returnUrl={your original request here}` so that you are taken to your original requested page once you are authenticated.

In your case, you would have to save to the current session the incoming `HTTP_REFERER` on the login page, then add that as a '?returnUrl=' for every link to the logout page. Then you'll have to add code to the Logout controller method to handle the redirect.

Note that this technique won't work with deep linking to restricted auth pages (as described in the first paragraph), since that would require two redirects. The referrer would not be valid at that point.

Comment: hah!  Thanks!  You kind of started me thinking in a direction.  Let me see if they accept having extra stuff in the query string.  If not, I could just drop the requirement.